# Остановка скоролла после прокрутки внутреннего блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

всем.

Мне необходимо сделать следующую вещь:

1. Есть страница.
2. Есть всплывающий блок с информацией, которая может скролится внутри данного блока.

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке не продолжалась скролится вся страница, когда контент проскролится до конца.

Comment: Необходимо body устанавливать overflow: hidden;

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо для `body` задавать `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

чтобы информация скроллилась только внутри одного блока, можно использовать `position: sticky` для плавающего блока с информацией, а у родительского блока задать `position: relative`. Только данное свойство поддерживается только современными браузерами и то не полностью [Ссылка на список поддерживаемых браузеров](https://caniuse.com/#search=position%3A%20sticky). свойства `top`, `bottom`, `right`, `left` будут давать отступы от родительского контейнера

Answer (score 0):

Пользователь **Vladiuslav Kim** скорее всего имел ввиду вот такой вариант решения:

```js
$('.popup').on('click',function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('open')){
    $(this).removeClass('open')
           .addClass('close')
           .text('закрыть');
    $('.popup_body').show();
    $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
  } else if($(this).hasClass('close')){
    $(this).removeClass('close')
           .addClass('open')
           .text('открыть');
    $('.popup_body').hide();
    $('body').css('overflow','auto');
  }
});
```

```css
.popup {display: inline-block; position: fixed; top: 10px; left: 10px; padding: 10px; cursor: pointer; z-index: 2;}
.popup.open {background: #7f7;}
.popup.close {background: #f77;}
.popup_body {display: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: rgba(255,255,255,.75); position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1;}
.popup_body .wrap {display: block; width: 80%; height: 80%; margin: 10%; overflow: hidden auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lobortis nunc et metus tincidunt egestas eu sed turpis. Morbi commodo luctus vestibulum. Cras eu massa lorem. Fusce fringilla arcu a risus tincidunt tempor. Suspendisse orci eros, iaculis sed laoreet non, cursus ut magna. Maecenas in nisl eget mi fermentum porttitor quis quis mi. Sed lacinia magna nec bibendum venenatis.

Etiam ut mauris sapien. Curabitur vitae ex eu tellus eleifend euismod nec non urna. Maecenas aliquet eu ligula sed tempus. Nunc aliquet feugiat faucibus. Pellentesque tempor mi ac sapien semper, ut bibendum ante suscipit. Nulla vel rhoncus ex. Ut et sem molestie, mattis augue vitae, pulvinar nulla. Nullam a tellus magna. Donec pellentesque nisl vitae ipsum tempor, eget venenatis turpis ullamcorper. Aenean lacinia est quis diam dictum, et dapibus ex luctus. Vivamus dignissim tortor sed neque mattis varius. Nam vestibulum neque id quam posuere mollis. Curabitur ut sem eget est sodales faucibus nec a urna. Donec semper consequat efficitur. Vivamus pharetra, sapien quis condimentum venenatis, ante ante ultrices purus, nec dignissim elit nunc quis urna.

Pellentesque elementum nisi id suscipit cursus. Proin venenatis enim in augue eleifend, ac ultricies purus sollicitudin. Proin vel neque quis lacus aliquet bibendum ut eget purus. Praesent odio dui, sagittis faucibus nunc sit amet, molestie facilisis sapien. Donec vehicula condimentum elit vel imperdiet. Integer lobortis ex sit amet dignissim scelerisque. Morbi egestas magna orci, sit amet imperdiet lacus sollicitudin a. Nullam sed aliquam diam, sit amet rhoncus nunc. Donec placerat eget arcu sed consequat. Maecenas congue feugiat ornare. Nam dignissim augue vel lacus dictum placerat.

Quisque lobortis, orci non malesuada tempus, dui purus vehicula ipsum, vel congue nulla dolor et velit. Aenean turpis nisi, posuere sed nisi rutrum, pulvinar pharetra libero. In nulla nisl, porttitor vitae elit ut, viverra pharetra odio. Morbi condimentum erat non nunc dignissim, ut sollicitudin odio tempor. Donec vehicula facilisis lorem a molestie. Donec ut leo pellentesque, hendrerit diam id, interdum nulla. Aliquam egestas accumsan urna, in luctus sem porttitor vitae. Vestibulum lectus quam, volutpat ut bibendum in, auctor auctor lorem. Etiam imperdiet, neque ut malesuada cursus, dui diam imperdiet metus, at accumsan risus metus ut elit. Vestibulum bibendum auctor mauris eu cursus. Nulla eleifend turpis eu rutrum dignissim. Curabitur lacinia arcu hendrerit euismod eleifend.

Quisque vulputate enim semper ligula auctor, eget finibus nisl venenatis. Nam sed dapibus elit. Quisque vestibulum quam erat, ac volutpat augue iaculis et. Nulla et commodo tortor. Vivamus nec vestibulum leo, in dapibus est. Morbi vehicula, ipsum dapibus aliquet varius, neque enim rutrum ipsum, quis dictum nibh mauris ornare est. Cras id diam felis. Duis ac ipsum dolor. Donec quis ornare tellus, sit amet luctus nisl. Etiam et ligula leo. </div>
<div class="popup open">открыть</div>
<div class="popup_body">
<div class="wrap">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lobortis nunc et metus tincidunt egestas eu sed turpis. Morbi commodo luctus vestibulum. Cras eu massa lorem. Fusce fringilla arcu a risus tincidunt tempor. Suspendisse orci eros, iaculis sed laoreet non, cursus ut magna. Maecenas in nisl eget mi fermentum porttitor quis quis mi. Sed lacinia magna nec bibendum venenatis.

Etiam ut mauris sapien. Curabitur vitae ex eu tellus eleifend euismod nec non urna. Maecenas aliquet eu ligula sed tempus. Nunc aliquet feugiat faucibus. Pellentesque tempor mi ac sapien semper, ut bibendum ante suscipit. Nulla vel rhoncus ex. Ut et sem molestie, mattis augue vitae, pulvinar nulla. Nullam a tellus magna. Donec pellentesque nisl vitae ipsum tempor, eget venenatis turpis ullamcorper. Aenean lacinia est quis diam dictum, et dapibus ex luctus. Vivamus dignissim tortor sed neque mattis varius. Nam vestibulum neque id quam posuere mollis. Curabitur ut sem eget est sodales faucibus nec a urna. Donec semper consequat efficitur. Vivamus pharetra, sapien quis condimentum venenatis, ante ante ultrices purus, nec dignissim elit nunc quis urna.

Pellentesque elementum nisi id suscipit cursus. Proin venenatis enim in augue eleifend, ac ultricies purus sollicitudin. Proin vel neque quis lacus aliquet bibendum ut eget purus. Praesent odio dui, sagittis faucibus nunc sit amet, molestie facilisis sapien. Donec vehicula condimentum elit vel imperdiet. Integer lobortis ex sit amet dignissim scelerisque. Morbi egestas magna orci, sit amet imperdiet lacus sollicitudin a. Nullam sed aliquam diam, sit amet rhoncus nunc. Donec placerat eget arcu sed consequat. Maecenas congue feugiat ornare. Nam dignissim augue vel lacus dictum placerat.

Quisque lobortis, orci non malesuada tempus, dui purus vehicula ipsum, vel congue nulla dolor et velit. Aenean turpis nisi, posuere sed nisi rutrum, pulvinar pharetra libero. In nulla nisl, porttitor vitae elit ut, viverra pharetra odio. Morbi condimentum erat non nunc dignissim, ut sollicitudin odio tempor. Donec vehicula facilisis lorem a molestie. Donec ut leo pellentesque, hendrerit diam id, interdum nulla. Aliquam egestas accumsan urna, in luctus sem porttitor vitae. Vestibulum lectus quam, volutpat ut bibendum in, auctor auctor lorem. Etiam imperdiet, neque ut malesuada cursus, dui diam imperdiet metus, at accumsan risus metus ut elit. Vestibulum bibendum auctor mauris eu cursus. Nulla eleifend turpis eu rutrum dignissim. Curabitur lacinia arcu hendrerit euismod eleifend.

Quisque vulputate enim semper ligula auctor, eget finibus nisl venenatis. Nam sed dapibus elit. Quisque vestibulum quam erat, ac volutpat augue iaculis et. Nulla et commodo tortor. Vivamus nec vestibulum leo, in dapibus est. Morbi vehicula, ipsum dapibus aliquet varius, neque enim rutrum ipsum, quis dictum nibh mauris ornare est. Cras id diam felis. Duis ac ipsum dolor. Donec quis ornare tellus, sit amet luctus nisl. Etiam et ligula leo.
</div>
</div>
```

Тут как раз суть заключается в том, что при открытие всплывающего блока, `body` выставляется `overflow: hidden`, а после закрытия окна ставится `overflow: auto`.